# Sort array object using surname in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is an array object with the value combination `name` and `surname`.
How to sort by `surname`?

```
var myArr  = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];
```

Comment: And the lefts are surnames or the rights?

Comment: The data is too good. Throw mixed case and some space padding to make it real.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the name after the comma is the last name, you could split each inner string into an array of first names and second names, and then use [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with destructuring to get the last names from both inner arrays. You can then use [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare both strings lexicographically. Lastly, you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) again to convert your inner arrays back into an array of strings.

See example below:

```js
const myArr  = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];

const res = myArr
  .map(name => name.split(', '))
  .sort(([_, a], [__, b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .map(name => name.join(', '));

console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, for a more efficient approach, you can split inside the `.sort()` method:

```js
const myArr  = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];
const res = myArr
  .sort((a, b) => a.split(',').pop().localeCompare(b.split(',').pop()))

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This looks cleaner but for a big array, this will be costly. You are making `2n` extra iteration.

Comment: @Rajesh fair point, I've added a more efficient approach, removing the additional `2n` work

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArr = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];

function sortBySurname(a, b) {
    if (a.split(',')[0] < b.split(',')[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.split(',')[0] > b.split(',')[0]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

myArr.sort(sortBySurname)
console.log(myArr)
```

**I strongly advise you to make the object like the below**

```
let myArr=[
    {
        firstName:"gopal",
        surName:"roy"
    },
    {
        firstName:"shaym",
        surName:"verma"
    },
    {
        firstName:"akash",
        surName:"jaiswal"
    }
]

function sortBySurname(a, b) {
    if (a.surName < b.surName) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.surName > b.surName) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
myArr.sort(sortBySurname)
console.log(myArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using split and compare.

```js
var myArr  = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];
function compare(a, b) {
    let sA = a.split(" ");
    let sB = b.split(" ");
    let lA = sA.pop();
    let lB = sB.pop();
    let n = lB.localeCompare(lA);
  
  if(n == -1) return 1;
  else return -1;
    return 0;
}
let sorted = myArr.sort(compare);
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Suggestions: **1.** Instead of `sB[sB.length - 1],`, you sould use `pop`. That does mutate array but here it does not matter. **2.** Instead of `if` ladder, use `string.localeCompare`. **3.** You do not need `$()` as you are not interacting with DOM. Put your code directly

Answer (score 0):

Going for one optimized for large data sets. Regex can be replaced with `trim`. Each record is parsed only once with cache and it will boost the sort even more if records change and need to be re-sorted on update.

```js
const data = [
  "   gopal  , roy   ", 
  "shaym,Verma", 
  " Akash, Jaiswal    "
]

const cache = {}

const getLastName = s => (
  cache[s] = cache[s] || s.split(',')[1].trim()
)

console.log(
  data.sort(
    (a, b) => getLastName(a).localeCompare(getLastName(b))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get surname then use `localeCompare`

```js
var myArr = ["gopal, roy", "shaym, verma", "akash, jaiswal"];
let out = myArr.sort((a, b) =>
  a.match(/, (.*)/)[1].localeCompare(b.match(/, (.*)/)[1])
);
console.log(out);
```